# I need fastest product update

Tags: product, import, optimization

I am saving products fetched from an XML document. I am using `$product->save()` but I need to do an update after the first save. But the `$product->save()` method is too much slow for update. I also tried `updateAttribute` to update product like:

```
public function productUpdate($productSkus=array(), $data, $storeId = 1){
            $ids=array();
            foreach($productSkus as $sku){
                $id = $this->_getid($sku);
                $attributesData = array("price" => $data['price']);
                array_push($ids,$id);
            }
             Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')
                    ->updateAttributes($ids, $attributesData, $storeId);
        }

        public function _getid($sku){
        $product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$sku); 
        if (!$product){
            return false;
        }
            return $product->getId();        
    }
```

What should I do? How can I update products faster? Imagine there is an XML document that is keeping data of 8000 products (including custom attributes), and it is dynamic, which means it can change anytime. So I need to update products fast, but `$product->save()` and the above code are not suitable for this situation.

Comment: Are you trying to give all products the same price?

Answer (score 4):

Firstly you could change `_getid($sku)` with `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getIdBySku()` which would be a bit more efficient.

Basically your function updates a group of products price yeah? When reading your code I can see that it should be able to simplify it to:

```
public function productUpdate($productSkus = array(), $data, $storeId = 1)
{
    $ids = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('sku', aray('in' => $productSkus))
        ->getAllIds();

    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(
        $ids,
        array('price' => $data['price']),
        $storeId
    );
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but this is not fast enough. I showed that function for an example . ıt can be anything to update product, but fast. Thats all i matter.Need faster update per product.

Comment: Oh right. Well you're not going to get a faster "magento" way to update the products. This way _will_ be faster than your example as it doesnt need to load every product individually before applying the update.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to make a external sql-request with `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` to the mage tables and call the reindex procedure. That's the fastet way. But: you need Deep knowing about the structure of the Database.
In this case all internal update rules disabled. I think this is a Option, but not recommendable.

Comment: You are right . I thought that but i have no chance to crash something.There is too much table related each other. But thank you for your answer.

Comment: Take a loook to this: https://github.com/avstudnitz/AvS_FastSimpleImport